# I want to call a method several times with different time interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'v a method -(void)showLyrics{}
I want to call that from another method but after a certain time, time invocation between each successive call is different. 
I am doing that this way

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];

[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:12];
```

Does any body know better way??

Answer (score 1):

Call it once

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}
```

Do your thing
then schedule the next

```
-(void)showLyrics {
    int d=2;
    //do your thing
    d+=3;//or whatever
    [self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:d];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer for your need. You need to add logic for setting the timer. Pass the time as a parameter to NSTimer and perform the method as required.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<accumSecs>
    target:self selector:@selector(showLyrics) 
    userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

More info about NSTimer Class: [NSTimer Apple Docs Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way i could think of is that you can create a timer function being called every second and then you can take a global variable whose value you can increase on every call and then with perhaps a switch statement you can make your decisions